# "Some Name Art" or "Some Name Arts"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, singular-vs-plural

I'm a Graphic designer and a pencil drawing artist. Whatever I make, I put something like this: **© Vikas Kumar arts & designs** in the footer of drawing/image and never worried about it.
Today, I just thought about it and found I've seen people using art/design instead of art**s**/design**s**

So I'm really wondering. Which of the following is correct in this case?

1. © Vikas Kumar Art & Design
2. © Vikas Kumar Arts & Designs

Comment: I was not trying to vandalize your title by the edit I was trying to make the question clearer.

Comment: I rejected because it was more about art/design as a "suffix" for a name. So name was important before it. Otherwise the difference could be understood from dictionary or other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend **Art / Design**

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[art](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/art)**

> (1) [ U ] the making of objects, images, music, etc. that are
>   beautiful or that express feelings
>
> **(2)** **[ U ]** the **activity** of painting, drawing, and making sculpture
>
> (3) [ U ] paintings, drawings, and sculptures

[ U ] meaning that it is **UNCOUNTABLE**: noun with no plural form.

[**design**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/design)

> (1) [ C ] a drawing or set of drawings showing how a building or
>   product is to be made and how it will work and look
>
> **(2)**  **[ U ]** the art of making plans or drawings for something

Notice that design maybe COUNTABLE but I've highlighted both (2) options.

**Art & Design** indicates that you have two main **activities** that already imply the production of multiple results (drawing**s**, picture**s**, image**s**).

Comment: By design, I mean digital work i.e., Graphic Design. still same answer?

Comment: @VikasKumar Yes, I think so

Comment: Hoping for some more answers.